# Debugging beginner's Objective-C program

Tags: objective-c, calculator

Okay, I'm kind of new to Objective-C, but I'm pretty familiar with OOP principles.  I think it's just the syntax that's getting me with this.

As an exercise for myself, I'm trying to build a simple command line calculator.  I typed up this program while checking my book (Stephen Kochan's *Programming in Objective-C: Third Ed.*), but it's throwing a lot of errors on me.

```
// Command line calculator in Objective-C

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// -------- Interface -------- //

@interface calc: NSObject{
    float x, y, result;
    char op;
}

- (float) add: (float) x, (float) y;
- (float) sub: (float) x, (float) y;
- (float) mul: (float) x, (float) y;
- (float) div: (float) x, (float) y;
+ (void) evaluate;

@end

// -------- Implementation -------- //

@implementation calc

    -(float) add: (float) x, (float) y{
    return x+y;
    }

    -(float) sub: (float) x, (float) y{
        return x-y;
    }

    -(float) mul: (float) x, (float) y{
        return x*y;
    }

    -(float) div: (float) x, (float) y{
        return x/y;
    }

    +(void) evaluate: (float) x, (char) op, (float) y{
        float result;
        switch(op){
            case '+':
                result = [add: x, y]; break;
            case '-':
                result = [sub: x, y]; break;
            case '*':
            case 'x':
                result = [mul: x, y]; break;
            case '/':
            case '÷':
                result = [div: x, y]; break;
        }
        NSLog(@"%s%f", "=", result);
    }

@end

// -------- Driver -------- //

int main(int argc, const char argv[]){
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    calc *cal = [[calc alloc] init];

    float x, y;
    char op;

    NSLog(@"%s", "Welcome to the calculator!\n Please enter a simple expresion (ex. 4+3)...");
    scanf("%f%c%f", &x, &op, &y);

    [cal evaluate: x, op, y];

    [pool drain];
}
```

I'm on a Mac, so I compile that with `gcc -framework Foundation main.m -o calc`, and it throws

```
calcBundle.m:14: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:30: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘,’ token
calcBundle.m:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:38: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘,’ token
calcBundle.m:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
calcBundle.m:42: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘,’ token
calcBundle.m:53:9: warning: multi-character character constant
calcBundle.m:59: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘calc’
calcBundle.m:59: warning: method definition for ‘+evaluate’ not found
calcBundle.m:59: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘calc’
calcBundle.m:59: warning: method definition for ‘-div:’ not found
calcBundle.m:59: warning: method definition for ‘-mul:’ not found
calcBundle.m:59: warning: method definition for ‘-sub:’ not found
calcBundle.m:59: warning: method definition for ‘-add:’ not found
calcBundle.m: In function ‘main’:
calcBundle.m:73: warning: ‘calc’ may not respond to ‘-evaluate:’
calcBundle.m:73: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
calcBundle.m:73: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept
calcBundle.m:73: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)
```

I know this is probably trivial stuff, but I've checked this against several examples, and can't seem to figure out what the root of these issues could be.

Thanks!

Comment: remove, in all methods you declared - (float) add: (float) x, (float) y; ===> - (float) add: (float) x: (float) y;

Comment: I don't have the book you mentioned, but after checking its [table of contents](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/objective-c/9780321712172), I suggest you take a look at the section named “Multiple Arguments to Methods” in Chapter 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should read an objective C beginners tutorial...

Your method declarations are wrong. They should look like

```
-(float) add: (float) x to: (float) y
{
    return x+y;
}
```

You don't comma-separate parameters, you try to make a "sentence" stating what the method does, in this case "add x to y".